# Storing last line of Docker log tail to a shell variable

Tags: linux, shell, docker, unix, scripting

All I am trying to do is to capture the last line of `docker log` to a variable in a shell script.

Here is my setup:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.7.2
WORKDIR /workspace
RUN pip install jupyterlab
EXPOSE 8888
ENTRYPOINT ["jupyter", "lab", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--allow-root", "--no-browser"]
```

**run.sh:**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

docker build -t ml/jupyterlab .
docker rm -f ml-jupyterlab
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v $(pwd)/src:/workspace --name ml-jupyterlab ml/jupyterlab

until [[ "$url_info" =~ "token" ]]; do
    url_info=$(docker logs ml-jupyterlab --tail 1)
    sleep 0.1 
done

echo "$url_info"
```

---

If it helps, here are the logins from the Docker container that and I am trying to capture the last line `http://(6f8bec0aa3d9 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=a6001a419b22d60dd3e5215d52794c5be7c0b368664c3505` in the `$url_info`

```
[I 05:22:37.925 LabApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 05:22:39.190 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 05:22:39.190 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab
[W 05:22:39.194 LabApp] JupyterLab server extension not enabled, manually loading...
[I 05:22:39.198 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 05:22:39.198 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab
[I 05:22:39.199 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /workspace
[I 05:22:39.199 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 05:22:39.200 LabApp] http://(6f8bec0aa3d9 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=a6001a419b22d60dd3e5215d52794c5be7c0b368664c3505
[I 05:22:39.200 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 05:22:39.204 LabApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-1-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://(6f8bec0aa3d9 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=a6001a419b22d60dd3e5215d52794c5be7c0b368664c3505
```

---

Executing the following

```sh
$ chmod +x run.sh
$ ./run.sh
```

gets into an infinite loop as `$url_info` remains `null`

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I resolved this by using the following script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

docker build -t ml/jupyterlab .
docker rm -f ml-jupyterlab
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v $(pwd)/src:/workspace --name ml-jupyterlab ml/jupyterlab

until [[ "${url_info}" != "" ]]; do
    docker logs ml-jupyterlab &> logs
    url_info=$(cat logs | grep token | head -1)
    sleep 0.1 
done


echo "$url_info"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that, within the 0.1s of pause, *multiple* log files are produced, including one with "`token`".

That would mean the latest line might *not* include token (which is already in the logs, in previous lines)

Replace your test with

```
until [[ "${url_info}" != "" ]]; do
    url_info=$(docker logs ml-jupyterlab --tail 100|grep token)
    sleep 0.1 
done
```

As long as `url_info` is empty, keep testing.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. However, this solution did not help me. If I run `url_info=$(docker logs ml.langiq.goviq.io --tail 100 | grep token)` and `echo $url_info` -- the output is still `newline`